# Ember.js: parallel loading parent and child models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have these routes:

- posts

  - index (all the posts)
  - single (with dynamic parameter *post_id*)

    - index (single post and it's comments view)
    - edit (editing post)

There are two separate requests for fetching post by ID and fetching post comments by post ID.
I want to load post and comments for **posts.single.index** route in parallel, because I have a post ID in route name and I do not have to wait when post will be loaded.

But Ember loads **posts.single** model, and only AFTER post it loads comments.

Is it possible to call child model in parallel with parent model?

I have found a solution when **posts.single** does not load anything, and **posts.single.index** calls two requests in it's own model. On the other hand, I should load post model within all **posts.single** child routes, such as **posts.single.edit**. It could be a problem, when application will be grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several techniques to load multiple resources in a `model`-Hook of a Route. Which ones best fits your needs or are even possible highly depends on your application. Especially the capabilities of the backend API used and if your Ember application uses [Ember Data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/) or plain [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)/ajax requests makes a big difference.

The simplest case is using Ember Data together with an REST API that follows [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/) and supports [inclusion of related resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes):

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model({ post_id }) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', post_id, { include: 'comments' });
  }
});
```

If you are using plain `fetch`, you could use `Promise.all()` to load multiple records in parallel:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  async model({ post_id }) {
    let [post, comments] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(`/posts/${post_id}`),
      fetch(`/posts/${post_id}/comments`),
    ]);
    return { post, comments };
  }
});
```

If you don't like the `Promise.all()` syntax with array destructing you might want to have a look at [`RSVP.hash()`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/#hash-of-promises). `rsvp` is bundled with ember by default.

If doing it with Ember Data but your API does not support side-loading, it's a little bit more tricky as you need to use a query to load the comments. It depends on your adapter configuration but I guess it would look like this:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  async model({ post_id }) {
    let [post, comments] = await Promise.all([
      this.store.findRecord('post', post_id),
      this.store.query('comment', {
        filter: {
          post: post_id
        }
      })
    ]);
    return { post, comments };
  }
});
```

You can't use multiple `model`-Hooks to load resources in parallel. `model`-Hooks of parent and child routes are executed in order by design. The `model`-Hook of a child route won't be fired before a `Promise` returned by it's parent `model`-Hook is resolved. Having that said there are still techniques to only load needed data and caching data that is shared between different child routes.

Let's take your example from the question and more detailed in the comments to this answer: Our frontend should show a post including it's comments on one route and a form to edit the same post on another route. Both routes need the same post resource but only one also needs the post's comment. The application should not load the post again if user transition from one route to the other and should not load the comments if user transitions to edit view.

A naive attempt would be a parent route that loads the `post` resource and two child routes, one for the view including comments and one for the edit form. I call this attempt "naive" cause it's failing in three ways:

1. The post and the comments are not loaded in parallel.
2. The resources aren't cached if a user transitions between the routes through a third one.
3. It mixes visual design with data loading.

The third point may be confusing. Indeed it's a common misunderstanding of nested routes in Ember. They are *not* meant to model data hierarchy but should be used to share visual UI between subroutes. It's not the `model`-Hook what count but the rendering of the child templates in parent's `{{outlet}}`.

All of your concerns could be easily solved by a service that caches resources client-side. This one of the main features of Ember Data. That's also one of the most hyped features of Apollo client for GraphQL. It's as simple as that: Most complex frontend applications need a client-side cache layer to prevent overfetching of resources. If you face that requirement I would recommend to use one of the existing solutions. For simple use cases you could also build you own service. A basic implementation could look like:

```js
import Service from '@ember/service';

export default class StoreService extend Sevice({
  postCache = new Map();

  loadPost(id) {
    let { postCache } = this;
    if (postCache.has(id)) {
      return postCache.get(id);
    }

    let request = fetch(`/posts/${id}`);
    postCache.set(id, request);
    return request;
  }
});
```

Comment: But if I fetch "post" and "comment"'s in "posts.single" route, it also will load "comment"'s for the "posts.single.edit" route, where they are unnecessary.
On the other hand, if "post" will be loaded from "posts.single" route, and "comment"'s - from "posts.single.index", they would not be loaded in parallel? Only comments after post?

Comment: Yes, route model hooks are not executed in parallel. But parent model hook is not executed again if child route changes. So a transition from `posts.single.index` to `posts.single.edit` won't cause `posts.single` model hook to be executed again. If you user will most likely visit the `posts.single.index` route before or after an edit, loading the comments in `posts.single` route won't be an issue. If that's not an option for you, you might need to do the fetching logic in a service, which provides a client-side cache. This would be a good point of time to introduce Ember Data.

Comment: So, there are no opportunities to fetch parent and child models in parallel?

Comment: There are many ways to fetch different resources in parallel but `model` hooks of parent and child routes are not executed one after each other. This is by design. Or to put it the other way around: If stuff should be executed in parallel, you should not split it up between parent and child model hooks.

Comment: Ok, thanks. While your answers did not resolved my problem, except the last one, they were helpul.

Comment: Maybe, you can duplicate your newest comment as a separatr answer? Looks like it is the better answer to my question, and I check it as that one that solved my problem.

Comment: I've extended my answer. Hope it makes it more clear what the route hierarchy should be used for and that there are better ways than using model hook to prevent refetching a resource.